# Setup error when installing Windows Phone 7 SDK 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, sdk, installation

Having Visual Studio 2010 Premium with SP1 installed on Windows 7 Enterprise 32bits Downloaded the SDK 7.1 ISO and unzip to a folder, tried to install from there, but keep getting this error:

Setup could not install the following component: Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Assemblies

The full event log is at:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=c49e721a7fa7913c&resid=C49E721A7FA7913C!901&parid=C49E721A7FA7913C!166&authkey=!AMBT2NlTo-h562Y

Basically it stops when the application tried to install WPSDK_en.msi module and got error:

Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action CA_SirepPrxyPortReg64_Install, location: c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\5.01\Misc\, command: "reg.exe" IMPORT "c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\5.01\Misc\SirepProxyPortsAdd.reg"

I have tried to manually import the .reg file, but still no luck. Anyone got better idea about this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you install with the Visual Studio Express that comes with the SDK?

Comment: I got VS 2010 already, so I didn't try to install VS Express.

Comment: Did you try running the installer "as administrator" with elevated privileges?
Also have you tried installing that package manually from the unpacked ISO?